# Blazor WASM don't update UI after refreshing data from server

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I've the following Page/Component with that code:

```
@page "/product"
@using FossCockpit5.Client.Services
@using FossCockpit5.Shared.Dto
@inject IProductService ProductService

<h3>Products</h3>

@if (products != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Short Name</th>
                <th>Short Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var product in products)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@product.Name</td>
                <td>@product.ShortName</td>
                <td><button @onclick="(x => Delete(product.Id))" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="oi oi-trash"></i> Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
} else
{
    <span>Loading...</span>
}


@code {
    private List<ProductDto>? products;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized called");
        products = await ProductService.GetProducts();
    }

    private async void Delete(string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Delete product {id}");
        await ProductService.DeleteProduct(id);
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted product {id}");
        products = await ProductService.GetProducts();
        Console.WriteLine($"Products loaded {products.Count}");
    }

}
```

The Console output is after I deleted one of two products:

```
Delete product ceef0312-39b5-4d64-8772-39583876ff2e
Deleted product ceef0312-39b5-4d64-8772-39583876ff2e
Products loaded 1
```

But the UI still displays two rows/products in the table. I would expect, that therefore `products` is updated the UI is also updated and the deleted product becomes removed, isn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try making `products` public and a property, not a field? If not, after you delete the product (`await ProductService.DeleteProduct(id)`) add `products.Remove(products.Single(x => x.Id == id));`

Comment: Both tried but also not working.

Comment: Try adding `this.StateHasChanged();` last thing I can think of right now.

Comment: That works fine :-/

Comment: Make that delete method return a 'Task' instead of 'void'.  And await it after the button is clicked.  The Blazor engine will re-render once the event has completed.  But, returning a void means the event completes before the await method inside the delete method have completed.  Hence, it's re-rendered before you've refreshed the data.

Comment: @NeilW thank you for pointing in the right direction. I had the same issue and although I know what async void does, I forgot to check that. And the reason why, because visual studio added the async for me. It got a nifty feature to add async to a method once you type await inside the body of the method. This might cause async void to appear in codes more often because it is easier to forget to change the void to Task.